# Create a modal view with navigation bar and back button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

I want to create a modal view with the navigation item (right view on my screenshot) and I want it to have a 'back button'. My app is TabBar application and I don't want this view to have a tab bar, but I want to load a previous view (left view on my screenshot) with a segue similar to the type "push". 
I can only create push segue to provide right navigation back to the view on the left, if it's loaded as a modal view, the NavigationBar & TabBar are gone. Any workarounds for this?
Thanks in advance!

[image: Here's my screenshot]

Comment: What's wrong with presenting a modal view(on the right) and having a back button to dismiss it to go back to the UITableView that is shown on the left?

Comment: Cause it's a UIWebView with dynamic content and I want the back button to be in the navigation bar

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just put a Navbar on the new view with a bar button item.  Create an action for the bar button item by control dragging from the bar button item to the .h of the view controller.  You can then use a delegate and protocol method to tell the first controller when the button has been pressed and have it use `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

So in your second view create a protocol with a method done, like this:

```
@protocol SecondViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

-(void) done;

@end

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController {
    ...
    id delegate;
}

...

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<SecondViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

-(IBAction)done:(id)sender;  //this will be linked to your nav bar button.
@end
```

then in your action from your button call this:

```
-(IBAction)done:(id)sender{
   [self.delegate done];
}
```

Your first view controller will need to implement the protocol `<SecondViewControllerDelegate>`

then in your first view controller, set it up as a delegate for your second view controller before you segue.

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"Second View Modal Segue Identifier"])
    {
        SecondViewController *viewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        viewController.delegate = self;
    }
}
```

lastly, catch the done call from the delegate in your first view controller:

```
-(void) done
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

That's how I have done it.  If you don't have a lot of experience with protocols and delegates it may seem confusing at first, but it has worked well for me.

Comment: excuse me if there are any typos, i typed it all from scratch just now.

Answer (score 6):

You will need to wrap your right hand side view controller in a new navigation controller. In IB, select it and choose the menu item `Editor -> Embed In -> Navigation Controller` and IB will show a nav bar which you can customize to your heart's content.

Comment: Will this let me present it as a modal view?

Comment: Yes, indeed. On the iPad you can have this be the smaller, centralized view. You have to implement your own buttons in the nav bar for dismissing.

Comment: Thanks. In iOS 7 if I just drag the navigation bar it will look bad since the background of "time bar", unlike navigation bar, does not have a gray background. But this method solved the problem and seems more elegant.