# Can you return data via dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: or do you need a segue for the return journey?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, storyboard, segue

I've got a `ViewController`, that has a `UIButton` which performs the following:

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender 
{
    NSLog(@"Button clicked, lets move to next controller to do stuff");
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toNextController" sender:nil];
}
```

This just moves onto my next `ViewController`, nothing amazing so far.

In the second ViewController, I will do some of my application logic, then return.

```
- (IBAction)backButtonPressed:(id)sender 
{
    NSLog(@"Back button clicked, lets just drop out of here...");
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (IBAction)saveButtonPressed:(id)sender 
{
    NSLog(@"save button clicked, lets send some data back");

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"backToMain" sender:nil];
}

-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{    
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"backToMain"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Preparing segue for backToMain");

        // Obtain handles on the current and destination controllers
        MainController * startingViewController;
        SecondController * destinationController;

        startingViewController = (MainController * ) segue.sourceViewController;
        destinationController = (SecondController * ) segue.destinationViewController;

        // set data on the main controller
        startingViewController.myString = @"SomeDummyString";
    }
}
```

What I have tried to do so far, is to create a second segue that links back to the main controller, and before performing the segue, grab a handle on it and set data. I'm not sure if that is the best way of navigating back or not.

**Question:**

Is it possible, to return data when doing a `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`, or do you need to implement a segue for the return journey?

Comment: I would not perform another segue back to the first controller.  As I understand it this creates a brand new instance of the Controller class and in effect you are just adding on more and more controllers as they segue back and forth to each other.  I would use a delegate/protocol method.  See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10841653/create-a-modal-view-with-navigation-bar-and-back-button/10841897#10841897

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out: [10841897](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10841653/create-a-modal-view-with-navigation-bar-and-back-button/10841897#10841897)

It describes using a delegate and protocol to send the information back and forth.  It can be slightly changed to fit your needs, just create a `savedWithData:` method that sends a dictionary or whatever data you want back to the first view controller rather than just the generic `done` which is described in the link.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like

```
[destinationController setSomeData:@"Sending Something Back"];
```

This will set an @property in your destinationController before it loads.