# Back button hidden in navigation bar (but still works)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2, xcode7

I have read about similar problems where the problem was caused by having multiple navigation controllers, but I only have one. This is my navigation flow.

> VC = UIViewController, NC = UINavigationController
>
> VC1 -modal-> NC -root-> VC2 -show-> VC3

**VC1** is not **embedded** in a navigation controller, I'm starting that modal segue using **performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:**.

**VC2** then is using a `show` segue to present **VC3**, which is the one where the back button is not visible. It still works though. But, it *does* appear if I exit to the home screen and then enters the app again, as shown here:

https://gfycat.com/VelvetyThisHamster.

Any ideas why this is happening?

edit: To make things clear: I want the button both visible and functioning (it's not that it's working that's the problem, but that it's hidden)

**EDIT 2:**

If I change my navigation flow to this

> NC -root-> VC2 -show-> VC3

then the back button works as intended. So the question is, how can I add a regular view controller without a navigation controller before the first navigation controller? I want it before because VC1 should not have a navigation bar and VC2 should be presented modally.

Comment: You should hide navigation back button on view will appear

Comment: In VC3? That makes the button both hidden and not functioning.

Comment: Could you add some code of that VC? Probably initialization and viewDidLoad?

Comment: present modal does not embed with navigation controller, thats the reason it s not show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the source of the problem, so I'll post it here in case someone else runs into the same problem.

The modal presentation between VC1 and NC was made from a background queue (by calling `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` in the completion handler of an NSURLSessionDataTask to be precise). By dispatching that line of code to the main queue the problem seems to disappear.

Answer (score 2):

try this

**Hidden**

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
{
super.viewWillAppear(animated)

 //use this
self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: false)
//else use this

 self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil


}
```

**Show**

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
{
super.viewWillAppear(animated)

 //use this
self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(false, animated: false)
 //else
 self.navigationController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.enabled = TRUE

}
```

**Update**

```
  override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
{
super.viewWillAppear(animated)

 //use this
self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(false, animated: false)
 //else
   let backButton  = UIBarButtonItem(title: "leftbutton", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "buttonMethod")

  self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton

}



 func buttonMethod() {
    print("Perform action")
}
```

Comment: When adding this the button became neither visible nor functional (it was functional before).

Comment: you want to hidden the button or else

Comment: I want the button to be both visible and functioning.

Comment: It does not seem to make any difference. The button is still hidden until I exit to the home screen and enters the app again.

Comment: The `backBarButtonItem` is apparently `nil`, that might have to do with the problem? EDIT: It is not, the property is still `nil` even after it becomes visible...

Comment: Thanks, but that just adds another button which doesn't have the default back arrow and it also disables the swiping gesture.

Comment: but this is the only way to do , if you want the swipe gesture add the details in inside the buttonMethod it will works

Comment: are you hidden in previous controller or any where

Comment: see this link bro it helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10841653/create-a-modal-view-with-navigation-bar-and-back-button

Answer (score 1):

Turn out, I had NavigationBar tint color set to "Clear". Once I changed it, the back button appeared.